# How to make array for a .push function. Getting "typeError: .push is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, error-handling, dom-events

I'm having trouble understanding how my code is resulting in an error. The line that gives off an error is

```
queryParts.push("&" + param + "=");
```

I can see that it inserts an array, but I don't understand how to make it an arrow and push.

```
function urlBuilder(param, paramValue){
                base_url = $('.service-container').data('base_url');
                var fullurl = window.location.href;
                var urlStart = fullurl.split("?").length > 1 ? fullurl.split("?")[0] : null;
                var urlQuery = fullurl.split("?").length > 1 ? fullurl.split("?")[1] : null;

                if (urlQuery) {
                    var queryParts = urlQuery.split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < queryParts.length; i++)
                    {
                        console.debug('query part: ', queryParts[i]);
                        if (queryParts[i].includes(param)) {
                            if (paramValue === null) {
                                queryParts.splice(i, 1);
                                } else {
                                    queryParts = "?" + param + "=" + paramValue;
                                }
                            } else {
                            queryParts.push("&" + param + "=");
                            } 
                        }
                        var rtnUrl = urlStart + queryParts.join("&");
                    return rtnUrl;
                    }else {
                        return base_url + '?' + param + '=' + paramValue;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You do

```
queryParts = "?" + param + "=" + paramValue;
```

After this, `queryParts` isn't an array anymore.

You probably wanted

```
queryParts.push( "?" + param + "=" + paramValue);
```

Answer (score -2):

This line makes your `queryParts` string.

`queryParts = '?' + param + '=' + paramValue`

To keep it array:

`queryParts.push('?' + param + '=' + paramValue)`